# How to extend css text animation over many lines?

Tags: css, hyperlink, line, transition

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style> 
a.nice-link {
  position: relative;
  color: #71ad37;
}

a.nice-link:after {
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #a5ff0e;
  min-height: 200%;
  height: 20%;
  width: 0;
  max-width: 200%;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
a.nice-link:hover {
  color: #71ad37;
}
a.nice-link:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

li {
display: inline-block;

}

.try{
width: 50px;
}
</style>

<div class = "try"><a class="nice-link" href=“http://katoliiklased.blogspot.com/2018/08/katekismuse-surmanuhtlust-kasitlev-uus.html“ data-text="Hello Bello Sello" target="_blank">Hello Bello Sello</a> 
</div>
```

The point of the code is: if you hover your mouse over the link, it will put transition into work, so that the text will highlight from left to right.

It works OK if there is one line of text. But if there is more, the transition works only on the first line.

How to make it work on other lines also? Either so that 1) the transition begins with the first line and then continues for other lines or 2) the text will transition as whole, with all the lines at the same time from left to right

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `white-space: nowrap;` in `a.nice-link:after` style.

Test it here.. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/aqd6ev39/1/